# LMER Factor vs numeric Interaction

Tags: r, lme4, interaction, ordinal

I am attempting to use lmer to model my data.

My data has 2 independent variables and a dependent variable.

The first is "Morph" and has values "Identical", "Near", "Far".
     The second is "Response" which can be "Old" or "New".
The dependent variable is "Fix_Count".

So here is a sample dataframe and what I currently have for running the linear model.

```
Subject <- c(rep(1, times = 6), rep(2, times = 6))
 q <- c("Identical", "Near", "Far")
 Morph <- c(rep(q, times = 4))
 t <- c(rep("old", times = 3),rep("new", times=3))
 Response <- c(rep(t, times = 2))
 Fix_Count <- sample(1:9, 12, replace = T)
 df.main <- data.frame(Subject,Morph, Response, Fix_Count, stringsAsFactors = T)
df.main$Subject <- as.factor(df.main$Subject)

 res = lmer(Fix_Count ~ (Morph * Response) + (1|Subject), data=df.main)
 summary(res)
```

And the output looks like this: 
[image]

The issue is I do not want it to do combination but an overall interaction of Morph:Response.

I can get it to do this by converting Morph to numeric instead of factor. However I'm not sure conceptually that makes sense as the values don't properly represent 1,2,3 but low-mid-high (ordered but qualitative).

So: 1. Is it possible to run lmer to get interaction effects between 2 factor variables?
2. Or do you think numeric is a fine way to class "Identica", "Near", "Far"?
3. I have tried setting contrasts to see if that can help, but sometimes I get an error and other times it seems like nothing is changed. If contrasts would help, could you explain how I would implement this?

Thank you so much for any help you can offer. I have also posted this question to stack exchange as I am unsure if this is a coding issue or a stats issue. However I can remove it from the less relevant forum once I know.

Best, Kirk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two problems I see. First, you should be using a factor variable for Subject. It's clearly not a continuous or integer variable. <strike>And to (possibly) address part of your question, there is an `interaction` function designed to work with regression formulas. I'm pretty sure that the formula interface will interpret the "*" operator that you used as a call to `interaction`, but the labeling of the output may be different and perhaps more to your liking.</strike>  I get the same number of coefficients with:

```
res = lmer(Fix_Count ~ interaction(Morph , Response) + (1|Subject), data=df.main)
```

But that's not an improvement.
<strike>However, they differ from the model created with `Morph*Response`. Probably there is a different set of contrast options.</strike>

The way to get an overall statistical test of the interaction is to compare nested models:

```
res_simple = lmer(Fix_Count ~ Morph + Response + (1|Subject), data=df.main)
```

And then do an anova for the model comparison:

```
anova(res,res_simple)
refitting model(s) with ML (instead of REML)
Data: df.main
Models:
res_simple: Fix_Count ~ Morph + Response + (1 | Subject)
res: Fix_Count ~ interaction(Morph, Response) + (1 | factor(Subject))
           Df    AIC    BIC  logLik deviance  Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq)
res_simple  6 50.920 53.830 -19.460   38.920                         
res         8 54.582 58.461 -19.291   38.582 0.3381      2     0.8445
```

My opinion is that it is sufficiently close to the boundary for stats vs coding that it could have been acceptable on either forum. (You are not supposed to cross post, however.)  If you are satisfied with a coding answer then we are done. If you need help with understanding model comparison, then you may need to edit your CV.com's question to request a more theory-based answer than mine. (I checked to make sure the `anova` results are the same regardless of whether you use the interaction function or the "*" operator.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure `interaction(Morph, Response)` is pretty much equivalent to `factor(paste(Morph, Response, sep = "."))`, so the real difference between `interaction(Morph, Response)` and `Morph * Response` is whether or not you get the main effects.

Comment: You might be right, in which case the suggestion to use `interaction is clearly not sensible. I'll strike it since the meat of the question is how to do cross-model comparisons.

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
So to clarify the idea is to make a model without the interaction effect, then a model with the interaction, and use an Anova to see how much better the model with the interaction fits the data. And you can get a p-value from this.
It seems like I can get the same value if I use anova(res) by itself (instead of summary(res) and instead of anova(res,res_simple) ). Is one preferred?
Thanks!

Comment: "Yes" to the first question; "Not so" to the second. I wouldn't have thought that those ANOVA calls would have two would have given the same result. `anova(res, res_reduced)` gives me two lines with numeric values and it is the difference in the model fits that need to be examined in light of the model degrees of freedom. `anova(res)` does not give the same results at all.

Comment: Hi
Just following up to ask if you know if there is a way to extract t-stats as well as p-values for the interaction? Or is that not possible to provide?
Thanks so much!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "t-stats". The question (at least as I understood it) was about model comparison and not so much about Wald-type tests where you might be using t-tests. The original output in the question had `t-values`.

Comment: Hi @IRTFM, I really think your answer helped me to continue with my model so thanks for this informative answers! Can I have your opinion in this question, is very similar to this but I can to see how to correlate the beta parameters from a drug response model and link those beta to a binary response. Hope you can have a look at it, please!!! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71634953/regression-parameters-from-lmer-and-binary-outcome

Comment: @Rachel : You posted that question in the wrong forum. SO is for difficulties in coding, not for difficulties in understanding the results of statistical models. You might ask for moderator attention to that question to migrate it to stats.stackexchange.com or consider subscribing and posting to the SIG-mixed-models R mailing list.